# Ignore all relative positioned parent divs wrapped arround absolute positioned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it's not possible with css, but I was trying to find some jQuery solution, so far no luck with answers on stack.

Anyway, the HTML order looks like this, and it needs to stay like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div class="dont-want-parents" style="position:absolute;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the question is how to position div with class "dont-want-parents" to the right-bottom of the wrapper div, ignoring all the relative positioned parents.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, eventually I figured out a solution:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  var parentoffset = $('.dont-want-parents').parent();
  var elwidth = $('.dont-want-parents').width();
  var offset = parentoffset.offset();
  $('.dont-want-parents').css('right', -offset.left + elwidth);
});
```

here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/onLxf6Lo/)

Comment: Then structure of your markup should be different..

Comment: @RayonDabre Well, I couldn't agree more, but it's not up to me to change it :) or better to say I would like to change it but I have to work with it like it is unfortunately

Comment: you need to cancel out the offsetting being done by the parent relpos elms; if one goes 150px, then yours need to go -150px...

Answer (score 0):

You can set them all back to `static` so that the one with `absolute` ignores them. Also, `top` and `left` are needed, as `position:absolute` only removes the element from the layout but not from its original position.

```js
$('.wrapper > div, .wrapper > div > div').css('position', 'static');
```

```css
div{
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

.dont-want-parents{
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div class="dont-want-parents" style="position:absolute;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another way is to just yank out the element from wherever it is and put it somewhere that is safe to be absolute.

```js
$('.dont-want-parents').appendTo('.wrapper');
```

```css
div{
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

.dont-want-parents{
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:relative;">
      <div class="dont-want-parents" style="position:absolute;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: to be more precise, this is a simplified version of the layout, but all the relative divs need to stay relative because there are lots of other elements depending on that.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer, the same thing can be done with CSS too, as I said relative must stay relative all the time

Comment: Nice edit with "append" :) , I have tried exactly like that but it breaks the layout, not sure if something can be done with the jQuery offset?